# Objective-C NSMutableArray mutated while being enumerated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I kinda stumbled into the error where you try to remove objects from an NSMutableArray while other objects is being added to it elsewhere. To keep it simple, i have no clue on how to fix it. Here is what i'm doing:

I have 4 timers calling 4 different methods that adds an object to the same array. Now, when i press a certain button, i need to remove all objects in the array (or at least some). So i tried to first invalidate all the 4 timers, and then do the work i want with the array, and then fire up the timers. I thought this would've worked since i am not using the timers anymore to enumerate through the array, but seemingly it doesn't work.

Any suggestions here?

Comment: This is also happening to me, but I am not removing anything from my NSMutableArray.  I am however, adding items to it in a background thread.  It only throws this error maybe once every 50 or 100, adds...and this is the only thread that ever touches the array in the entire app...

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's nothing to do with your timers. Because (I assume) your timers are all working on the same thread as your modifying method you don't need to stop and start them. iOS doesn't use an interrupt model for timer callbacks, they have to wait their turn just like any other event :)

You're probably doing something like

```
for (id object in myArray)
   if (someCondition)
       [myArray removeObject:object];
```

You can't edit a mutable array while you're going through it so you need to make a temporary array to hold the things you want to remove

```
// Find the things to remove
NSMutableArray *toDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id object in myArray)
   if (someCondition)
       [toDelete addObject:object];

// Remove them
[myArray removeObjectsInArray:toDelete];
```

Comment: I think the last two lines should read "`for (id object in toDelete)
    [myArray removeObject:object];`"

Comment: @TobiasKlüpfel - you're absolutely right - I've edited my answer.

Comment: Just use `-removeObjectsInArray:`. Also, if accessing via indices you can modify while iterating over it.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche - the first part of your comment is excellent advice; I've edited my answer :)

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche - However, the second part is very dangerous; if you're using an index to iterate through an array though a 100 item array and remove one, your app will crash with an exception when it asks for item at index 100. It will also skip the item just after you have done the remove!

Comment: The point about the second part was not that it's preferrable, but that you can edit a mutable array while iterating over it - just not when using enumeration.

Comment: I prefer playing it safe; too many subtle bugs for my liking!

Comment: I used this one, thanks a lot chap, it worked like a charm :) So basically, what you can't do is enumerate through an array, and remove objects in that same array during the enumeration? correct? :)

Comment: correct :) (And this rule is true for _any_ mutable collection i.e. NNSMutableSet etc)

Comment: @daidai - I think your edit was too hastily rejected so I've made the change anyway - my answer compiles now :) Good spot!

Comment: Is it OK to use normal for loop, and take care of index when removing object from NSArray ?

Comment: @bluesm Technically, yes that would work. However, it woudln't get past peer review in any team I'm in :) The code would look horribly complicated and I bet there would be an off-by-1 bug somewhere in there! Unless there's a vital speed/memory increase you get from that, I'd go for clearer code every time.

Comment: @deanWombourne,  +1 for this `You can't edit a mutable array while you're going through `

Answer (score 24):

You can do it this way:

```
for (id object in [myArray copy])
   if (someCondition)
       [myArray removeObject:object];
```

Like @deanWombourne said, "you can't edit a mutable array while you're going through it", so what i'm doing here is to create an autoreleased copy of your original array to enumerate the objects, so you can safely remove anything you want.

More clear and less boiler code (i think!).

**Update**: Removed autorelease call since this was an old answer, pre ARC.

Comment: Very nice :) Might be a performance problem if your `myArray` is very large and you're only removing a few items but I certainly like it's elegance!

Comment: Most elegant here, and of course `autorelease` is not needed with ARC.

Comment: In addition to the performance issue @deanWombourne mentioned earlier, using `[myArray copy]` for each iteration could slow down your program. I would strongly recommend creating an `NSArray` instance (e.g., `NSArray *tempArray = [myArray copy];`) before the for loop and using that instead.

Comment: Hi @pxpgraphics - If you were doing a `for(n=0;n<myArray.copy.count;++n) { ... }` style loop then you're correct. However, fast iterations don't work like that - it enumerates all the items of the array _once_ and then passes over them - (a good article is [here][http://nshipster.com/enumerators/]). Because of this your optimisation doesn't speed things up in this case. It might make more readable code though, which is alway a Good Thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the @synchronized() directive to lock the array while you mutate it:

```
if (someCondition) {
    @synchronized(yourArray) {
        [yourArray removeObject:someObject];
    }
}
```

More info at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocThreading.html

Answer (score 0):

Though above all are true... I would share my experience with

> mutated while being enumerated

What I was doing was simple but totally error-full:

```
for (id obj  in d.dataDashBoardGraph) {
    [tmpData addObject:[obj valueForKey:[[dataToShow[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"] objectAtIndex:1]]];

    ...
}
```

Even this caused `mutated being enumerated error`. To get rid of it:

```
for (id obj  in d.dataDashBoardGraph) {
   NSString *data = [dataToShow[i] copy];
   [tmpData addObject:[obj valueForKey:[[data componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"] objectAtIndex:1]]];

    ... 
}
```

Then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for (id object in [myArray reverseObjectEnumerator])
if (someCondition)
   [myArray removeObject:object];
```

If you remove object at index x => The index of objects at index x + 1, x + 2.... will be changed.
So when you use  [reverseObjectEnumerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/reverseObjectEnumerator) , the index of objects in array after remove some objects will still correct.

Hope this help.
(accepted answer is a clear solution.)

Answer (score -1):

NSMutableArray can not be mutated while being enumerated, you may create a minor delay before calling your action:

```
 for(id key in resultsDictionary) {
                if ([key isEqual:whichButtonString]) {
                   // [resultsDictionary removeObjectForKey:whichButtonString];
                    [self performSelector:@selector(removeKeyFromDictionary:) withObject:whichButtonString afterDelay:1.0];
                }
            }
```

Then

```
-(void) removeKeyFromDictionary : (NSString *) incomingString {
[resultsDictionary removeObjectForKey:incomingString];
```

}